# What is the opposite of "free," as in "gluten-free/free of gluten"?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

I am looking for a one-word antonym for "free" in the context of "a lack of something." For example: "pain-free/free of pain," "error-free/free of errors," "gluten-free/free of gluten"? To say "full" isn't quite right. If a forty-page text contains 1-2 typos, it is not "error-free," but it is also not "full of errors." What about "gluten"? If a pizza isn't "gluten-free," what is it? Gluten-full? Gluten-regular?

Comment: It contains gluten. Not every thought can be expressed using an adjective. That's why we have other parts of speech in the first place.

Comment: gluten-laden is when there is a LOT of it

Comment: Contains gluten is the answer, as seen on packaging. See also: *contains peanuts*, or *contains sugar*. It also works with the "errors" example: the forty-page text contains errors, but doesn't work well with the experience of pain where you could say: I experience pain or I have some pain.

Comment: "I contain pain."  Hmm, works for me.   Although, I can think of at least three different meanings  ...

Comment: If the pizza has an extraordinary amount of gluten, you could say that it's _glutenous maximus_ ;^)

Comment: @J.R. In my response to your comment on my A, I almost congratulated you for not "finding some way to go there, yet".   Oh well.

Comment: You don't want the *antonym* "full of errors", you want the *negation* "not free of errors".

Comment: This sounds glutenous...

Comment: Single word requests should be accompanied by a sentence showing how the OP will use the word.

Answer (score 3):

There is no universal one-word replacement for -free.

In the context of foods the appropriate portmanteau is ***gluten-containing***

***-containing*** can be used universally, although there are other alternatives depending on specific food components (eg, *sugared* for *sugar-free*)

another word that can be applied almost universally in the context of nutrition is ***-fortified***

***-enriched*** is another alternative but strictly applied refers to addition of an existing constituent (that has been lost during processing for example).

***-full*** is applied in many instances (as in painful), but doesn't sit well with most foods (although ***-filled*** very often does).

Comment: I agree with most of this, but I think you're a little off on "fortified". That suggests an extra helping - not the case, here; no gluten was explicitly added to the *glutenic" pizza. // You know, there's two different kinds of "fortified wine", both of which start with 'normal' wine; one adds vitamins, one adds alcohol.

Comment: you can say gluten-fortified flour [http://www.aaccnet.org/publications/cc/2002/September/Pages/79_5_737.aspx]. I think you are confusing 'fortification' with 'enrichment'.

Comment: That link doesn't work for me. // Yes, I'm certainly thinking of *enrichment*.   Would you say that *fortified* could have either meaning?  ("__-containing" or "__-enriched") /  Would you agree that "*fortified wine*" means "wine with an extra additive", not "wine containing the normal ingredients in their normal proportions"?

Comment: both terms are valid although there is subtle difference in meaning. Fortification is a global term whereas enrichment, strictly applied, refers to adding an existing constituent (for eg, which was lost during food processing).

Answer (score 1):

The opposing suffixes for -free are

- -filled for nouns
- -able for verbs

e.g.,

- Tax-free vs taxable
- Gluten-free vs gluten-filled
- Lead-free vs lead-filled

Answer (score 1):

Rule of thumb is that most people will assume that a food traditionally made with gluten contains gluten, thus using no modifier when talking about it ("pizza"). Otherwise, it's called "gluten [food]", using *gluten* as an attributive noun:

> Most celiacs would not try that approach of eating toppings off of a gluten pizza. — [Food That Touches A Wheat Product](https://www.celiac.com/forums/topic/48375-food-that-touches-a-wheat-product/)

> In fact, in many ways it is easier and quicker to bake a gluten free bread loaf than it is to bake a traditional gluten bread. — [18 Tips for Gluten Free Bread Baking](https://gfjules.com/18-tips-for-gluten-free-bread-baking/)

> I don't think I will ever bake gluten bread. — [Soft Gluten Free Sandwich Bread Recipe](https://alittleinsanity.com/soft-gluten-free-sandwich-bread-recipe/)

> Tastes most like traditional gluten pasta. Cooks up al dente, and reheats well the next day. — [Gluten Free Spaghetti Pasta 12 oz](https://www.influenster.com/reviews/barilla-gluten-free-spaghetti-pasta-12-oz)

> I cannot tell difference between this and gluten pasta! Same texture as regular wheat pasta. — [Gluten Free Elbows - 12oz](https://www.target.com/p/barilla-gluten-free-elbows-12oz/-/A-47759741)

As the last example indicates, sometimes it's also called "wheat [food]".

Alternatively, I've seen "non-gluten-free":

> Eating a gluten-free pizza made up of eight slices would give you around 120g carbs, whereas this amount would be doubled if eating a non-gluten-free pizza. — [Is Gluten Free Pizza Lower In Carbs?](https://www.amazinghomemadepizza.com/is-gluten-free-pizza-lower-in-carbs/)

(That's also abbreviated as "[non-GF](https://www.glutenfreeliving.com/gluten-free-lifestyle/tips-advice/kitchen-appliances-risk-of-cross-contamination/)".)

This is a pattern that generalizes better than the others (the antonym of "tax free" is certainly not "wheat", though you can use "[non tax free](https://businesstech.co.za/news/wealth/247567/heres-how-much-you-can-earn-when-you-invest-tax-free/amp/)" in a pinch), though as with the examples above, there may be a better way in the specific context to say it that doesn't generalize ("tax free" becomes "taxed", "error free" becomes "error ridden" or even "sloppy").

Answer (score 0):

The pizza with gluten is "conventional".

"Glutinous" sounds like it would be right, but it isn't necessairly so (a thing can be glutinous with no gluten!).   "Glutenous" then ought to make sense, but isn't a word - likewise "glutenated".

"Gluten-inclusive" would be accurate, tolerable, and likely to peeve the gluten-intolerant.

"Gluten, free" or "Free gluten" would be excellent ways to advertise your pizzeria's generosity.

"Non-error-free" is "unedited".   "Painful" is a word.

Comment: I'm going to start using gluten-full, no matter if it exists or not :-

Comment: glutenated isn't a word - how so?

Comment: @JanDvorak IDK, ignorantly so?  A quick search (done *after* answering, of course) reveals "glutenated depresion" - presumably what happens to the gluten-intolerant when they watch me eat.   Glutacular ...

Comment: It's worth pointing out that [_glutinous_](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/glutinous) means "glue-like", which is why something can be "glutinous with no gluten". That said, [_glutenous_](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/glutenous?r=66) can mean "containing gluten", or it can mean ["glutinous"](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/glutenous). It's a sticky situation.

Comment: Well said, @J.R.  I figured that *glutenous* would mean "containing gluten" if it was a word - but that it isn't. // (For the sticklers - yes, I missed a letter in "depression".  I failed to depress the appropriate key - or, if it's the second one I missed, to re-press it.)

Comment: I agree with coining the word "glutenated". Or "gluten-inclusive".  Or, to adopt the market-driven tone of gluten-free: "gluten-rich"

Answer (score 0):

I don't suppose one could use "pro-gluten"? As in, 'our pro-gluten pizzas'?

Comment: Since the question asker hasn't been on the site in over eight years, we're unlikely to ever know. Also if you're writing an answer, it's best not to make it all questions.

Comment: See if you can find any examples of this being used and [edit] if you find any. We're looking for answers that have support.

Comment: Hi Ali. Your profile shows you as new here. Welcome to ELU! Do give some time to the [tour] when you can. "Good answers" here are usually more than just a suggestion. An example of use in a publication or advertisement would be fitting for this case. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

I like "glutenated", and I also propose "englutened". Of course they're not words but the language grows through such neologisms -- which is a word :).

Comment: Glutenated beverages like beer.